# Ошибка Object Moved TFS 2015

Tags: tfs

Установлен Tfs 2015 версии 14.95.25122.0 (Tfs2015.Update2)

Хочу настроить билд проекта. Скачиваю Agent-а для выполнения сборки.

Выполняю настройку агента. После его конфигурации, на веб-портале tfs во вкладке пул агентов, вижу зарегистрированный agent, который в активном состоянии(зеленый).

Перехожу на вкладу "Сборка". Запускаю сборку. Сборка запускается, но завершается практически мгновенно. В логах агента вижу следующую ошибку:

> 16:29:47.611717 JobManager.StartJob(job.JobId =
>   25f444d0-43b1-4593-a4e0-22280cf3adf0) 16:29:47.615623 JobInfo.ctor
>   16:29:47.615623 JobInfo.ctor - leave 16:29:47.615623
>   JobManager.StartJob - calling JobWriter.StartJob 16:29:47.617576
>   JobWriter.StartJob - enter 16:29:47.617576 JobWriter.StartJob -
>   (SKIPPING)first renew 16:29:47.802134 JobWriter.StartJob - start
>   continual renewing 16:29:47.813852 AuthorizationType : OAuth
>   16:29:47.826547
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 16:29:47.829476
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException:
>   Object Moved
>
> 16:29:47.829476    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage
>   response)
>
> 16:29:47.829476    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__79.MoveNext()
>
> 16:29:47.829476 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown ---
>
> 16:29:47.829476    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.829476    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.829476    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__76`1.MoveNext()
>
> 16:29:47.829476 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown ---
>
> 16:29:47.829476    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.829476    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.d__6.MoveNext()
>
> 16:29:47.830453 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown ---
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.d__39.MoveNext()
>
> 16:29:47.830453 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown ---
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.ConnectionHelper.GetConnection(Uri
>   serverUri, VssCredentials credentials)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobWriter.StartJob()
>   16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage
>   response)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__79.MoveNext()
>
> 16:29:47.830453 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown ---
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__76`1.MoveNext()
>
> 16:29:47.830453 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown ---
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.d__6.MoveNext()
>
> 16:29:47.830453 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown ---
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.d__39.MoveNext()
>
> 16:29:47.830453 --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown ---
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.ConnectionHelper.GetConnection(Uri
>   serverUri, VssCredentials credentials)
>
> 16:29:47.830453    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.JobWriter.StartJob()
>   16:29:47.830453
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 16:29:47.836312 Process logging event with context handler.
>   16:29:47.841194 BaseLogger.LogConsoleMessage(scope.JobId =
>   25f444d0-43b1-4593-a4e0-22280cf3adf0, message = ##[error]The Agent
>   failed to start this job. Error: Object Moved) 16:29:47.841194
>   JobManager.LogConsoleMessage (scope.JobId =
>   25f444d0-43b1-4593-a4e0-22280cf3adf0, message = ##[error]The Agent
>   failed to start this job. Error: Object Moved) 16:29:47.841194
>   JobManager.LogConsoleMessage - message enqueued 16:29:47.842171
>   [5effa6a7-16ea-421b-afc0-da8d7f8609ef][25f444d0-43b1-4593-a4e0-22280cf3adf0]##[error]The
>   Agent failed to start this job. Error: Object Moved 16:29:47.844124
>   JobManager.FinishJob(jobId = 25f444d0-43b1-4593-a4e0-22280cf3adf0,
>   result = Failed)

По какой причине такое может быть, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил следующим образом.

1. Обновился на TFS 2017.
2. В TFS 2017 появилась настройка с говорящим названием Public Url(В TFS 2015 она называлась по-другому, и по этой настройке была рекомендация, что использовать URL с привязкой к адресу localhost). В итоге в этой настройке у меня был адрес, отличающийся от публичного адреса. 
   В настройках сервера TFS было: http://localhost:8080/tfs 
   Внешний адрес для TFS сервера: http://myserver:8080/tfs

После того, как я в настройках tfs указал правильный публичный адрес, мой агент заработал.

Как результат, обновление на TFS 2017 помогло мне понять суть моей проблемы, хотя в итоге можно было и не выполнять обновление, зная, что какая настройка означает в TFS 2015. Но как уже отметил, она там имела совершенно другое название(если не ошибаюсь, то она там называлась *Site Url*)